# Laravel scope model count from relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to count unread messages from conversation. This is my table structure.

```
mysql> describe conversations;
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |                             |
| other fields which are not needed            
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> describe messages;
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id              | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| is_seen         | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |                         |
| conversation_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Relationships between tables are working fine :

```
//Conversation.php 
// this return all messages from the conversation
public function messages(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Message','conversation_id');
    }


// I got stuck in this function
public function scopeUnread($query){
        return $query->whereHas('messages', function($q){
            $q->where('is_seen',0);
        });
    }
```

**I am trying to count all unread messages from conversation, I did the function above, so I can get number of unread from conversation like this**

```
Conversation::find(1)->unread();
```

Comment: what's the issue ?

Comment: @jaysingkar When i call `scopeUnread` function inside Conversation.php, I expect to get unread messages.

Comment: which version of laravel you are using ?

Comment: @jaysingkar laravel 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call scopes before you end the query (in your case before `->find(1)`.

Like this:

```
Conversation::unread()->find();
```

Edit:
Nvm, I didn't understand what you want.

This is how you would count unread messages from a conversation:

```
$c = Conversation::find(1);
$unreadCount = $c->messages()->where('is_seen', 0)->count();
```

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is not to write this `$c->messages()->where('is_seen', 0)->count();` inside a function so i can call it directly within `Conversation` Model. Anyway thank you!